# How can I execute an org-babel file from the command line?

Tags: org-babel

Is there a way to execute a whole buffer's worth of code blocks, in an org file, and save them all in that org file, headlessly, from the command line?

Here's what I've tried so far, but it's not working (just hangs):

```
emacsclient -a --eval '(find-file "index.org")(org-babel-execute-buffer)(save-buffer)'
```

I'm also trying this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# Update Org-Babel files
#
emacsclient -a --batch --eval "
    (progn
      (require 'ob-core)
      (dolist (file command-line-args-left)
        (with-current-buffer (find-file-noselect file)
          (org-babel-execute-buffer))))
  " "$@"
```

But this just returns `nil` and `symbol is void`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```el
#! /bin/bash
# Update Org-Babel files
#
emacs --batch -l ob -l ob-shell --eval "
(let ((org-confirm-babel-evaluate nil))
      (dolist (file command-line-args-left)
        (with-current-buffer (find-file-noselect file)
          (org-babel-execute-buffer)
          (save-buffer))))
  " $*
```

Depending on what language(s) your source blocks use, you might have to load additional languages.

You can't use `--batch` or `-l` with `emacsclient` - see its man page.

Comment: I'm getting `No org-babel-execute function for sh!`.

Comment: You will need to load all the languages you use or else initialize `org-babel-load-languages`, e.g `...-l ob -l ob-shell -l ob-python -l ob-org ...`. The only one that's enabled by default is `emacs-lisp` AFAICT.